# Absolutely positioned button not centering in IE11

Tags: css

It's a landing page with a big background image assigned to the body. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but it's not centering in Internet Explorer 11.  Below is my code.  Please help, thanks!

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="landing-bg">
...
<a class="watch-trailer-btn" href="#"><span>Watch Trailer<span></a>
...
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.landing-bg{    
    width: 100%;
    height: 1350px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.watch-trailer-btn{
    position: absolute; 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 490px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #f1d948;    
}
```

**UPDATE** w/ example

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tmgoade/1ufss8ht/)

**UPDATE** w/ direct link

http://jsfiddle.net/tmgoade/1ufss8ht/

Comment: Which center is off? Vertical or Horizontal?

Comment: @Paulie_D It's the horizontal center. It's currently at the very left of the screen.

Comment: You've set a width and used `left:0` I think that's what IE is keying off. Why do you have `right:0`?

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle that's not working?

Comment: @Bhojendra Please see post with the updated JSFiddle link.

Comment: @isosmall Sorry, jsfiddle is not working for me.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal I put the direct link above to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
.landing-bg{    
    width: 100%;
    height: 1350px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.watch-trailer-btn{
    position: relative; /*Change to relative*/
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*left: 0;*/
    /*right: 0;*/
    top: 490px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #f1d948;    
}
```

You can also do:

```
.landing-bg{ 
    width: 100%;
    height: 1350px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; /*Add*/
  }
.watch-trailer-btn{
    position: relative; /*Change to relative*/
    display: inline-box;
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    /*margin: 0 auto;*/
    /*left: 0;*/
    /*right: 0;*/
    top: 490px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #f1d948;    
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u92ry6nu/

Comment: You should specify what you made changed specifically to make it work?

Comment: Thank you! Putting the text-align: center; in the container .landing-bg works!

Answer (score 4):

There are various techniques for vertical centering but when dealing with absolute positioning it is perhaps preferable to use

`top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);`

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.landing-bg{    
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
}
.watch-trailer-btn{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #f1d948;    
}
```

```html
<div class="landing-bg">

    <a class="watch-trailer-btn" href="#"><span>Watch Trailer</span></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="modal-box visible form-modal">
    <!-- MODAL 01 -->
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="text-container">
            <h2>Vivez Lorem</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. .....</p>
        </div>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.modal-box .inner-container {
   position: relative;
   width: 465px; 
   /*width: better put in percentage; */
   left: 9px;
   background-color: #FFF;
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-top: 10%;
   margin-bottom: 10%;}
```

Here is the working [example](http://jsbin.com/xocadeboro/1/).

Comment: Thank you for contributing!